# How to add independent "Tags" to Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags

I'd like to create a custom taxonomy called "Tags", just like the native one that can be found on Posts, **with the same name/slug but independent from it**:

```
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
```

I know that I can add the line above during the CPT creation but this would make the Tags shared between posts and my CPT. That is something I'd like to avoid so I wanted to use the following code:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Tags', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Tag', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Tags', 'textdomain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Tags', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Tags', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'                => null,
    'parent_item_colon'          => null,
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Tag', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Tag', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Tag', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Tag Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate tags with commas', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove tags', 'textdomain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used tags', 'textdomain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'No tags found.', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Tags', 'textdomain' ),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'tag' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'tag', 'book', $args );
```

My doubt is that at the bottom of the official "[Register Taxonomy Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)" there is a section dedicated to "Reserved Terms" and, among them, there's also "tag".

So my question is, how do I change the code written above to better comply with the Wordpress guidelines and avoid potential conflicts?

The "reserved terms" refers only to the "register_taxonomy()" function or also the 'rewrite' argument?  Can I change the name of the "registered taxonomy" but keep the 'rewrite'  => array( 'slug' => 'tag' ) ? Would this potentially generate conflicts?

Is enough to change the "register_taxonomy" into:

```
register_taxonomy( 'book_tag', 'book', $args );
```

but keep unchanged

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tag' )
```

Would this be a correct way of handling this and avoid any conflict? Is there a better way?

Thanks for your time and support

Answer (score 0):

`tag` is a reserved term because it's the native query var for querying by slug with the `post_tag` taxonomy (see [`WP_Query` Tag Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters)).

You *could* technically register your taxonomy with `tag` as the taxonomy name, **however**- you'd have to change the `query_var` argument to something other than `tag` (setting it to `true` uses the taxonomy name, it also accepts a string).

Anyway- it's probably safer and just all around better to use `book_tag`.

As for the `rewrite` `slug` being `tag`- if the native `post_tag` taxonomy is also using this slug, your new taxonomy will capture all of those requests. Wordpress will query for the slug in your `book_tag` taxonomy instead of `post_tag`.

There is a little trick to fix this- check if the requested term exists in `post_tag`, and make WordPress query there instead. The obvious caveat here is that you can never have terms in both taxonomies that share the same slug. To do this, we hook `request`, which fires before WordPress does any of its own query parsing:

```
function wpd_modify_tag_requests( $request ) {
    // is this a book_tag request?
    if( isset( $request['book_tag'] ) && 1 == count($request) ){
        // does the slug exist in post_tag? 
        if( get_term_by( 'slug', $request['book_tag'], 'post_tag' ) ){
            // move slug over to tag, and delete book_tag
            $request['tag'] = $request['book_tag'];
            unset( $request['book_tag'] );
        }
    }
    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpd_modify_tag_requests' );
```